# Twilio Call Queue Management

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I need a basic queue management with one twilio number and five agents.

When a call is received, the call is put in a Queue.

How do I remove the calls from the queue and assign to the agents as they are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can do this in a couple of ways. The simple way will mean your agents would need to dial into the queue, the harder way will setup an automated system that dials your agents when there is a new call in the queue.

So, the simple way. In response to the initial call you should use TwiML to [`<Enqueue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue) the call, adding it to the back of the queue.

```
<Response>
  <Enqueue>support</Enqueue>
</Response>
```

Then, you could have another number that the agents dial into that calls the [`<Queue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/queue) and connects them to the first person waiting, using the following TwiML:

```
<Response>
  <Dial><Queue>support</Queue></Dial>
</Response>
```

The harder way involves using [Twilio's TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter) to manage the queue and dialling to agents. It's a little too much to build out your application for you here, but TaskRouter allows you to [define a Workflow](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/workflow-configuration) for incoming calls, which are turned into Tasks, and [assigned to active Workers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/handling-assignment-callbacks).

There is a good blog post here on how to [setup TaskRouter as a support desk](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/02/multi-channel-support-desk-taskrouter.html). There is a good [contact center example application here too](https://github.com/nash-md/twilio-contact-center).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: In manual queue, can I have the agent accept the call using Queue UI instead of dialing another number. With TaskRouter, Is there a way to distribute the calls equally among the agents?

Comment: TaskRouter is the way to distribute the calls equally among agents, or you have to build that distribution yourself.